# How to clear keybinding

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap

I'm in Linux (Fedora 17 x86_64, 3.6.11) and my laptop's PageUp key has gone ultrasensitive on me.  I'd like to disable it (remap it to nothing at all) as I've never liked it where it is (right next to my up arrow keys).

I'm sure that I can use xmodmap to do it, but I don't even know where to start.

** EDIT **

I'd like something like:

```
keycode 112 = NULL PAGE_UP
```

Comment: But have you tried, eg any research?

Comment: Yes I have indeed.

Comment: @Rui I'm fine removing what I added to the question; but I'm going to go ahead and add what you've deleted back in as a comment; unfortunately when users don't "show their work" the quality of response across all stack exchange sites drops dramatically. I"m happy to, alternatively, edit the tone as well.

Comment: From Q: I have read through the man page for `xmodmap` top to bottom. It is not useful for a beginner (makes a great reference for an experienced user, I assume, like the other man pages I use on a regular basis). My biggest problem is in understanding all the opaque terminology they've invented for it. I can see how to remap a single key in its various modified forms, but there's no "IGNORE THIS KEY COMBINATION" option that I've been able to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My biggest problem is in understanding all the opaque terminology they've invented for it. I can see how to remap a single key in its various modified forms, but there's no "IGNORE THIS KEY

In your case *"ignore this key"* translates to *"remap to nothing"*.
Open a terminal and run:

```sh
xmodmap -e 'keycode 112='
```

your <kbd>PageUp</kbd> key will suffer a sudden death.

Re-enable it with:

```sh
xmodmap -e 'keycode 112= Prior'
```

To permanently disable it add:

```sh
keycode 112=
```

to your `~/.Xmodmap`

Test your config file:

```sh
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```