# Disable F6 key in gnome / linux

Tags: linux, gnome, keyboard

I have a very annoying bug where my keyboard send the F6 command after I press the up arrow.  I do not use F6 for anything, so is there something I can do to just disable the F6 key?  Disabling on boot is fine, of a bash script that can disable/enable/toggle is fine too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found this link which seems to solve the problem.  Note that F6 is keycode 72. [Solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67865/how-to-clear-keybinding)